# Did New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential double base64 encode for CustomKeyIdentifier and Value?

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am using New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential to create a KeyCredential for an application. [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationkeycredential?view=azureadps-2.0)

At first, I base64 encode the Thumbprint

```
$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cer.Import("C:\Users\PFuller\Desktop\abc.cer") 
...
$bin = $cer.GetCertHash()
$base64Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)
...
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId <id> 
                                    -CustomKeyIdentifier $base64Thumbprint  
                                    -Type AsymmetricX509Cert 
                                    -Usage Verify -Value $base64Value
```

But the result on AAD manifest is **double base64 encoded**:

```
"keyCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": "base64(base64Thumbprint)",
            ...
        }
    ],
```

According to [Microsoft identity platform application authentication certificate credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials)

The customKeyIdentifier should only **base64 encoded once** and store on manifest's keyCredentials.

Did I misuse this cmd or something wrong here? becase after I turned the manifest to base64 encoded once, every thing works properly.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi, is my answer helpful? If there is any update from your side, please let me know:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, both `customKeyIdentifier` and `value` are double base64 encoded when we create a KeyCredential for an application using `New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential`.

After that I use the following code to get the access token with this cert:

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("{clientId}")
               .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "{tenantId}")
               .WithCertificate(cer)
               .Build();
var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
```

I find that we can successfully get the access token with correct roles.

So I think `New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential` base64 encodes `customKeyIdentifier` and `value` for another time. But it also handles them correctly when we use the X509Certificate to get an access token.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late response. In my test, no matter customKeyIdentifier is base 64 encoded once or twice. Use the same customKeyIdentifier to compose JWT can both get the access token from client_credentials flow.